# CMake Error: The source directory ".../code/mongo-cxx-driver" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: mongodb, cmake

I'm following the MongoDB C++ Driver Quickstart Guide: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Quickstart-Guide-(New-Driver)

I'm in the `mongo-cxx-driver` directory and
when I run:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

I get the following error:

> CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/Waley/code/mongo-cxx-driver" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt."

Is this something I can fix?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in `mongo-cxx-driver` you should enter the folder `build` and execute your CMake command from there. That's exactly what is stated in the webpage you are referring to.